# IE8 float right drops images on a new line

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 links made up of text and a image and it works everywhere except in IE 8 compatibility mode.  I am told that there are users of this application that use IE 8 compatibility mode so it has to work in that browser environment.  The issue is that the image is being dropped down to the next line.

Here is what it should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/idJZ6.png

Here is what it looks like in IE 8 compatibility mode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSTCe.png

Here's what it looks like in context of the screen it's on:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t6wm.png

I was able to the issue reproduce in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dmase05/C6etX/

The site is using Twitter Bootstrap so I'm using some of those classes for the grid and floats.

**One thing that makes this harder to troubleshoot is that I found running the jsfiddle in IE 9 in IE 8 Compatibility mode shows the issue, however, running IE 10 in IE 8 Compatibility mode looks correct.**  I don't have access to a native IE 8 install, but I am told that it looks fine there.

Here's the HTML (using Bootstrap CSS):

```
    <div id="divCalendarFooter">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="span3 pull-right">
                <a id="lnkSelectColumns" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="pull-right">
               Choose Columns &nbsp;<img src="http://db.tt/cEFFCjw0"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3 pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="pull-right">
                    Print Calendar &nbsp;<img src="http://db.tt/u94nalQx"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4 pull-right">
                <a id="aShowPrintByDateRange" href="#" class="pull-right">
                   Print Calendar By Date Range &nbsp;<img src="http://db.tt/u7OxN09k"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>​
```

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I've just this morning downgraded IE10 to IE9 because the IE8 developer mode doesn't render floats like the IE8 browser does. Thanks microsoft :(

Comment: @Gerbus http://modern.ie - thanks Microsoft!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the same problem in a real copy of Internet Explorer 8 (in IE8 standards mode).

Rather than using `img` tags, you can add the blue icons as background images using CSS.  For instance, the CSS would look something like this:

```
#divCalendarFooter a {
    padding-right: 36px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

#lnkSelectColumns {
    background: url(http://db.tt/cEFFCjw0) no-repeat center right;
}

#printCalendar {
    background: url(http://db.tt/u94nalQx) no-repeat center right;
}

#aShowPrintByDateRange {
    background: url(http://db.tt/u7OxN09k) no-repeat center right;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C6etX/6/.  As you can see, I had to add an ID to the second link.